# node.js I/O non-blocking - understanding when it is most beneficial

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous

After reading about event loops and how async works in node.js, this is my understanding of node.js:

- Node actually runs processes one at a time and not simultaneously.
- Node really shines when multiple databse I/O tasks are called. 
  It runs faster (than blocking I/O) because it doesn't wait for the response of one call before dealing with the next call. And while dealing with the other call, when the result of the first call arrives, it "gets back to it", basically going back and forth crossing calls and callbacks, without leaving the OS process idle, as opposed to what blocking I/O does. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

But here's my question:
Non-blocking I/O seems to be faster than blocking I/O only if the entity (server/process/thread?) that handles the request sent by node, is **not the node server itself**.

What would be the cases when the sever handling the request is the same server making the request? If my first bullet is correct, in this case a blocking I/O will work faster than non-blocking if it uses different threads for the task?
Would file compression be an example to such I/O task that works faster on multithreaded blocking I/O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit of non-blocking operations is that a relatively heavyweight CPU thread is not kept busy while the server is waiting for something to happen elsewhere (networking, disk I/O, etc...).  This means that many different requests can be "in-flight" with only the single CPU thread and no thread is stuck waiting for I/O.  A burden is placed back on the developer to write async-friendly code and to use async I/O operations, but in a heavy I/O bound operation, there can be a real benefit to server scalability.  The single thread model also really simplifies access to shared resources since there is far, far less opportunity for threading conflicts, deadlocks, etc...  This can result in fewer hard-to-find thread synchronization bugs that tend to only nail your server at the worst time (e.g. when it's busy).

Yes, non-blocking I/O only really helps if the agent handling the I/O operation is not node.js itself because the whole point of non-blocking I/O in node is that node is free to use its single thread to go do other things while the I/O operation is running and if it's node that is serving the I/O operation then that wouldn't be true.

Sorry, but I don't understand the part of your question about file compression.  File compression takes a certain amount of CPU, no matter who handles it and there are a bunch of different considerations if you were trying to decide whether to handle it inside of node itself or in an outside process (running a different thread).  That isn't a simple question.  I'd probably start with using whatever code I already had for the compression (e.g. use node code if that's what you had or an external library/process if that's what you had) and only investigate a different option if you actually ran into a performance or scalability issue or knew you had an issue.

FYI, a simple mechanism for handling compression would be to spool the uncompressed data to  files in a temporary directory from your node.js app and then have another process (which could be written in any system, even include node) that just looks for files in the temporary directory to which it applies the compression and then does something more permanent with the resulting compressed data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From the third part of your answer I understand that file compression should probably be handled by a different thread or server, otherwise it will block the node event loop.
What is a good practice to forking such task to a different thread?

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're asking about.  There are many different schemes for dealing with multiple processes from having a deamon running at all times that you use some form of interprocess communication to communicate with to spawning a temporary child process using [node's capabilities](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for that and there are many architectural/performance/throughput/memory usage tradeoffs involved in choosing one way over another.

Comment: I see there are various ways of dealing with CPU consuming tasks. I will consider the pros and cons of each. Anyway, your answer gave me better understanding of my main question, which was about non-blocking technique, I appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of it. Will wait a bit to see of more answers come along. If not, will do :)

Comment: @user3800705 - I added one more idea to the end of my answer.